# Use variables to access the right data in Firebase database using Vue.js

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm building an app with Vue.js and Firebase as a backend. I'm retrieving data based on a URL parameter, for instance: http://localhost:8082/?link=fe3b096a8ab1f4d7146ba0ce7555336a85f0532272e748358ec81beb2b17e494

Then my code retrieves the values owneruid and tripuid thanks to this URL parameter. It allows me to get info from the user, such as userphotourl, username, tripphotourl, tripname, tripbegindate, tripenddate. So far it displays the values, so all good.

The variables owneruid and tripuid are stored, but because of the asynchronous, I included calls to functions that use this variables in my first .then(photosSnap => {, to run the rest of the code in a logical order.

Now I want to get all the photourl of all the photos of one trip (tripuid) of a user (owneruid). The database structure is like this :

[image]

How can I retrieve all the photourl and display them using v-for ?

My code :

```js
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld'
    
import Firebase from 'firebase'
    
let config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyA9ap6pzsvkOv4tA2rgM6GKl2snKabzel4",
    authDomain: "travelertest-e316f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://travelertest-e316f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "travelertest-e316f",
    storageBucket: "travelertest-e316f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "605093453777"
}

let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let database = app.database();
    
let photosRef = database.ref('trips');
    
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
          
let link = GetURLParameter('link');  
    
console.log(link);

//var owneruid = 'bCbADd1qJqhoVbDg0QCDIlq5eMx1';
//var tripuid = '-Kiqtd3BxPX8WvpOTxsW';
var owneruid = '';
var tripuid = '';

database.ref(`links/${link}`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
var obj = photosSnap.val();
owneruid =  obj['owneruid'];
tripuid = obj['tripuid'];
console.log(owneruid);
console.log(tripuid);
getUserInfo(); 
getTripInfo();
getTripDate();
});

function getUserInfo() {
    database.ref(`user_profiles/${owneruid}`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var obj = photosSnap.val();
    var userphotourl =  obj['photourl'];
    var username = obj['name'];
    $('.userphoto').attr('src', userphotourl);  
    $('.username').html(username);
    });
}
    
function getTripInfo() {
    database.ref(`trips/${owneruid}/trips/${tripuid}`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var obj = photosSnap.val();
    var tripphotourl =  obj['photourl'];
    var tripname = obj['name'];
    $('#tripcoverphoto').attr('src', tripphotourl);   
    $('.tripname').html(tripname); 
    });
}
        
function ConvertDate(DateInSeconds) {
    var tripbegindateseconds = DateInSeconds;
    var tripbegindatefull = new Date(0); // The 0 there is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
    tripbegindatefull.setUTCSeconds(tripbegindateseconds);
    var tripbeginmonth = tripbegindatefull.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var tripbeginday = tripbegindatefull.getUTCDate();
    var tripbeginyear = tripbegindatefull.getUTCFullYear();
    tripbegindate = tripbeginday + "/" + tripbeginmonth + "/" + tripbeginyear;
    return tripbegindate;
}  
   
function getTripDate() {
    database.ref(`trips/${owneruid}/trips/${tripuid}`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var obj = photosSnap.val();
    var tripbegindate =  ConvertDate(obj['begindate']);
    var tripenddate = ConvertDate(obj['enddate']);
    $('.tripbegindate').html(tripbegindate);    
    $('.tripenddate').html(tripenddate);    
    });
}
    
/*database.ref(`links/${link}`).once('value').then(photosSnap => {
    var obj = photosSnap.val();
    var owneruid =  obj['owneruid'];
    var tripuid = obj['tripuid'];
});

console.log(owneruid);
console.log(tripuid);*/
    

export default {
    name: 'app',
    firebase: {
        photos: photosRef
    }
}
```

```html
    <div id="app">
        <div id="profile">
            <img class="userphoto" src="" /><br/>
            <font size="6" class="username"></font><br/>
            <img id="tripcoverphoto" src="" alt="" /><br/>
            <font size="8" class="tripname"></font><br/>
            <font size="6" class="tripbegindate"></font><font size="6"> - </font><font size="6" class="tripenddate"></font>
        </div>
        <div id="photoslist" v-for="photo in photos">
            <img id="image" height="400" width="400" src={{photo}}/>
        </div>
    </div>
```